# rounding series of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am trying to solve one of the coursera's homework for beginners.

I have read the data and tried to convert it as it shown in the code piece below. I am looking for the frequency distribution of the considered variables and for this reason I am trying to round the values. I tried several methods but nothing give me what I am expecting (see below please)..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# loading the database file
data = pd.read_csv('gapminder-2.csv',low_memory=False)
# number of observations (rows)
print len(data)
# number of variables (columns)
print len(data.columns)


sub1 = pd.DataFrame({'income':data['incomeperperson'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True),
                     'alcohol':data['alcconsumption'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True),
                     'suicide':data['suicideper100th'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)})

sub1.apply(pd.Series.round)

income = sub1['income'].value_counts(sort=False)
print income
```

However, I got

```
285.224449      1
2712.517199     1
21943.339898    1
1036.830725     1
557.947513      1
```

What I expect:

```
285    1
2712   1
21943  1
1036   1
557    1
```

Comment: `sub1.round()` should do - requires pandas 0.17.x, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Series.round()](http://Series.round())

```
ser = pd.Series([1.1,2.1,3.1,5.1])

print(ser)

0    1.1
1    2.1
2    3.1
3    5.1
dtype: float64
```

From here you can use `.round()`, the default is set to `0` per docs.

```
print(ser.round())

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    5
dtype: float64
```

To save changes you need to re-assign it to `ser=ser.round()`.