# Pandas series has np.round error that dataframe does not

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am not able to np.round with a series but can with the parent dataframe.

I am hoping to set-up a table of the `df.describe()`, but only the needed column. I can round the full `df.describe()` with numpy, I can print the unrounded series or use [Series.round()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848459/rounding-series-of-pandas-dataframes), but I cannot np.round the series.

```
np.round(x.describe(),2) # works
round(x.mass.describe(),2) # works
x.mass.describe().round(2) # works
```

This does not work, though:

```
np.round(x.mass.describe(),2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-175-01a34f55ca1f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.round(x.mass.describe(),2)

  File "C:\Users\DRB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2786, in round_
    return round(decimals, out)

TypeError: round() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Is there any reason why? Documentation for numpy.round does not specify.

I am using the latest Anaconda install, 4, with pandas 0.18.0 and numpy 1.10.4.

Comment: this should work, you'll need to post raw data and code that reproduces this error

Comment: With numpy 1.11.0 and pandas 0.18.1, it works. Which versions are you using?

Comment: Using pandas 0.18.0, and numpy 1.10.4.

Comment: @double0darbo, I recall years ago that Spyder did some weird indenting -. try your code in another text editor -- Sublime Text --  and see if problem persists.

Comment: I ran with python from command line, and still have the same problem.

Comment: @double0darbo, if you stop mixing questions, you might more answers. Move to indexing prob to a new question.

Comment: Not trying to confound the issue, but it's difficult to predict where the problem lies or what might help. Trimmed info back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the version of pandas you are using is 0.18.0 then issue is a bug on numpy that insists on call with positional arguments a 'sub-class' method. The bug has been raised [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12600) and will be fixed in version 0.18.1.